# Calculate the sum for 3 CCK fields with Rules in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, entities, rules

I have 4 stock fields (Stock 1, Stock 2, Stock 3 and TOTAL STOCK) and I want to set up a rule to calculate ["+"] the sum of Stock 1, Stock 2 and Stock 3 fields, and automatically appear in TOTAL STOCK field.

example -> http://ucreateawebsite.com/DRUPAL/dalexgrup/pt

What event, conditions and actions Should I use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer:

***For Event I used:***

- After updating an existing commerce product

***For Conditions I used:***

- Entity has field

  - Parameter: Entity: [commerce-product], Field: field_stock1
- Entity has field

  - Parameter: Entity: [commerce-product], Field: field_stock2
- Entity has field

  - Parameter: Entity: [commerce-product], Field: field_stock3
- Entity has field

  - Parameter: Entity: [commerce-product], Field: field_totalstock

***For Actions I used:***

- Calculate a value

  - Parameter: Input value 1: [commerce-product:field-stock1], Input value 2: [commerce-product:field-stock2]; Provides variables: Calculation result for Stock1  and Stock2 (stock1_plus_stock2_result)
- Calculate a value

  - Parameter: Input value 1: [stock1-plus-stock2-result], Input value 2: [commerce-product:field-stock3]; Provides variables: Calculation result for stock1-plus-stock2-result and Stock3 (stock1_plus_stock2_result_plus_stock3)
- Set a data value

  - Parameter: Data: [commerce-product:field-totalstock], Value: [stock1_plus_stock2_result_plus_stock3]

You can see what I wrote on http://ucreateawebsite.com/DRUPAL/dalexgrup/pt.

Answer (score 0):

You can try playing with:

**Event**: on updating content

**Conditions**: entity has field (to have it available in actions) for stock1, stock2 and stock3

**Actions**: set data value

Comment: ok I tried, but no success.